# ngf-select pops on when anchor tag is pressed too

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

So i try to do a file dropbox. I use `ngf-select`. Inside the div I added `a` tag to remove a file.

But when I press a tag , `ngf-select` pops up too. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNxko.png)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Okey. kind of fixed it myself. 
If any of you have similar problem here is the answer:

`<a>` tag called a method. In the method call event.stopPropagation(); it will cancel upcoming event's such as ngf-select pop up.